# Apache poi excel - How to get the name of the style from style index

Tags: java, apache-poi

When i'm try to check style is present or not using apache poi, i'm getting only index of the style. After check the style i want to display the name of the particular style. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance..

**Example**

```
checkStyle = 2
if(currentStyle != checkStyle)
"Left Align Not Present"
else
"Left Align Present"
```

***This is my code***

```
if(row?.getCell(curColOp)?.getCellStyle()?.getIndex() == tcOpRow?.getCell(curColOp)?.getCellStyle()?.getIndex()){
   style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex())
   style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND)
   row?.getCell(curColOp).setCellStyle(style)
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the block of code you are having problems with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [POI Excel: get style name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675062/poi-excel-get-style-name)

Comment: which was never answered correctly @LittlePanda