# Apache Poi how to detect a template color?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to copy everything from a `XSSFWorkbook` to a `SXSSFWorkbook`, because I can't write the `XSSFWorkbook` to disk due to an `OutOfMemoryException`.

For this I've been searching the web all day for the most efficient way to copy sheets between workbooks without loosing any formatting, styling, etc. I used [this forum thread](https://coderanch.com/t/420958/open-source/Copying-sheet-excel-file-excel) to create my own util class work with the excel versions mentioned above.

So far it copies everything necessary, with just a little hiccup. On one sheet in the original file, the cell background is defined within the `Theme Colors`. This causes the new file to actually display a different color than it should.

Original color:
[image]

New color:

[image]

Also, in case you don't know what I mean with `Theme Colors` (I just realized that both colors are at the same spot):

[image][image]

This is the code I use to copy the `CellStyles`:

```
int styleHashCode = oldCell.getCellStyle().hashCode();
CellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(styleHashCode);
if (newCellStyle == null) {
    newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
    newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());
    styleMap.put(styleHashCode, newCellStyle);
}
newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);
```

As of now, this causes said hiccup. As I just found out what causes this issue, I had not much time to test all my own thoughts on how to work this out, but I would be grateful for every hint/solution that exists for this issue.

So to sum it up:

**How can I copy the color for `Theme Colors` used in the `CellStyles`?**

---

Please note that I can easily replicate the color with RGB values, the issue lies with the identifying of `Template Colors`.

EDIT: I just found that the call to `ThemesTable.inheritFromThemeAsRequired(XSSFColor color)` seems to cause my issue. Yet I haven't found any way to unset the theme for the workbook.

Comment: Have you read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39667614/get-cell-colour-with-apache-poi)?

Comment: @deHaar I Just now read it while I was working on a similar test case. As of now, I think I will simply copy the `getFillForegroundColorColor().getRGB()` for each `CellStyle` to circumvent any issue the `Theme Colors` can cause like this. Though still, any other solution is welcome

Comment: Here's [another possibly interesting question with an accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675062/poi-excel-get-style-name). This looks pormising, but I don't know if you have tried that already.

Comment: @deHaar as I couldn't get it to work to load the custom theme into my new workbook, I had another look at the second link you posted and that actually worked for me. And the performance is still nice, so thumbs up to that find

Comment: You're welcome, I'm always interested in nearly everything concerning apache-poi ;-)